# Can functions that are run inside class definitions find a reference to that class?

Tags: python, python-3.5

I'm writing a function that modifies a class. Currently I'm doing it like this (copied from my unit tests):

```
class ChildClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.foo = 123

class Subject:
    def __init__(self):
        self.child = ChildClass()

# This is the function I'm talking about. It modifies the class "Subject".
defer_property(Subject, "child", "foo")

assertEqual(123, Subject().foo)
```

Since the function modifies the class, I would prefer to run it inside the class definition like this:

```
class Subject:
    defer_property("child", "foo")

    def __init__(self):
        self.child = ChildClass()
```

It would be great if the function could get a reference to the class from context:

```
def defer_property(member, property_name):
    cls = get_class_reference_somehow()   # I want this magic function

    prop = property(
        # ...
    )

    setattr(cls, property_name, prop)
```

Is this possible?

Any alternative way to reach a similar end would be awesome. I really don't want to involve metaclasses though.

Answer (score 4):

> Any alternative way to reach a similar goal end be awesome.

Decorator:

```
def defer_property(member, property_name):
    def _(cls):
        pass # do stuff here
        return cls
    return _
```

Usage:

```
@defer_property("child", "foo")
class Subject:
    pass
```

Comment: I didn't consider that, thanks. It's way better than what I'm currently doing.

Answer (score 3):

The class does not exist until after the body is evaluated, so no. A class statement

```
class MyClass(object):
    foo = 3
    def __init__(self):
        pass
```

is roughly equivalent to

```
body['foo'] = 3
def init(self):
    pass
body['__init__'] = init
# *Now* create the class object
MyClass = type('MyClass', (object,), body)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your function doesn't have to set attibute on it's own, it can return it instead:

```
def defer_property(member, property_name):
    prop = property(
        # ...
    )
    return prop

class Subject:
    foo = defer_property("child", "foo")
```

Comment: How do I access the Subject instance from within `defer_property` though?

Comment: @Hubro: technically, `Subject` is global, so if you use the function only to modify `Subject`, you can refer to `Subject` in function's body. I wouldn't recommend it, though. Otherwise, you probably can't. That's ok if you only need `Subject` to set attribute to the class (you didn't said anything about it in question), but well, maybe this is not an answer...

Comment: Actually, I'm being stupid. The instance will be passed to the getter and setter as the first argument.